# How to use MSMQ in Azure applications

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, msmq, netmsmqbinding

**My current example:**

Machine A - PRIVATE queue name - AdminQueue
Machine B - PRIVATE queue name - ShippingOrders

I have a console application running in Machine-A which pushes messages to PRIVATE queue (machine B- ShippingOrders)

I have a WCF service application hosted in IIS to consume these messages from "ShippingOrders" and send response back to machine-A's AdminQueue.

Is it possible to consume message from Azure cloud application and send response back to AdminQueue? Is MSMQ available in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

> Is MSMQ available in Azure?

In Azure platform, we could create and use MSMQ on Azure Virtual Machine. You could check following document before using MSMQ on Azure VM.

[Guidelines for Running MSMQ in Azure Virtual Machines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn529082.aspx)

After published your application to Azure, I suggest you use Azure Storage Queue or Azure Service Bus Queue instead of MSMQ. Here are the differences between them. You could choose one of them to use.

[Storage queues and Service Bus queues - compared and contrasted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted)